# how to connect my android application with database(mySql) by using magento

Tags: magento-1.9, android

I am using android studio for development of android eCommerce application. i want to connect my application to magento. i am new developer so i have not too much knowledge about this.

My database is in mysql and mysql connect to magento. so how my app will connect to magento?
If I connect my app to magento through web service but i have no idea about how to connect through web service to magento.

Comment: You can use the magento API's here is the document hope that will help http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html if you need an API's for your custom module then you have to create your own API's (Module Specific). Write your complete requirement to get better help :)

Comment: Refer To this Link It May Be Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112174/android-connect-to-magento